# Is “卧草” a proper Chinese word?

Tags: word

In football games, I heard people use "卧草" for time-wasting actions near the end of a game. Is "卧草" a proper Chinese word? I did not find it in dictionaries.

Comment: What is a *proper* word?

Comment: @user3306356, to me a proper word is a word that is accepted by at least some authoritative dictionaries.

Comment: Then it's not. Or you can define some sort of "dictionary of Chinese network slangs" as authoritative

Answer (score 6):

It's not.

However it does share the same pronunciation of `我操` or `我肏`, basically the Chinese equivalent of `WTF`. Term `卧草` became more popular due to widely existing profanity filtering on different internet platforms which mostly will filter out the origin term, while it also feels *slightly* more polite (Think about shoot vs. shit).

Comment: Thanks! I thought "卧草" has it literal meaning "lying on grass", describing faking injuries.

Answer (score 0):

I would say 卧草 is a grammatically valid phase which means "lying on the grass". No dictionary would include it because if so, the dictionary would be too thick -- you can lie on anything.